# Is it best Practice to Call Web API in Worker service?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Worker service in my application .

Using HTTP Client to call WEB API's is best practice or not?

```
var test = await client.GetAsync (this.webRootPath + "Alert/SendEmail");
```

Comment: If your worker service interacts with some external web API to transfer data (get or transfer), I do not see any issue, but if you call an endpoint in your worker service, I think it would be better to make an internal call, have a service for the logic and call that service directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to call external services, `HttpClient` is the way to achieve it. Make sure you are using [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to surface the client in your service.